# 'Make text smaller' actually reduce the size of the window with terminal or iterm2 in mac, instead of the font size

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, window, terminal.app, iterm2

If I am in full screen mode the shortcut cmd+ and cmd- increase or reduce the size of the text, as it should. Otherwise the shortcuts just reduce or increase the size of entire window, they don't change the size of the text! These commands do not work in this way on all the others applications, like browser, text editor and so on.
There is a way to fix it such way that cmd +/-, or eventually another shortcut, increases/diminish the font size without changing the number of rows, (without the necessity to work in full screen mode) ?

Answer (score 0):

The font size does change, but the number of rows and columns of characters is automatically preserved, for good reason.

Terminal-based apps can screw up their layouts if you change the number of rows or columns of characters, so it's conventional for terminal emulator apps to keep the number of rows and columns the same when you change the text size. This is what 99.9% of terminal users want and expect. Terminal emulator apps shrink (or grow) the "chrome" (UI borders) of the window to match, so that there isn't awkward unused whitespace around the newly-shrunken text (and so all the rows and columns are still visible even with newly-enlarged text). Again, this is a convention that works for the vast majority of serious terminal users.

It's also conventional to let you change the number of rows and columns of the emulated terminal by drag-resizing the window.

So the workaround is to drag-resize the window if you want more rows and columns, and change the font size if you want each character to take up less room on the overall Mac screen (as opposed to the emulated terminal screen, which is just a window on the Mac screen).

Comment: In ubuntu does not work like that in full size-window. Ctrl + just increases the font without changing the number of rows. Also in the mac it does not alter the window dimension while you are in full screen mode, but only alters the actual size of the font.

Comment: Yes, in full-screen mode, resizing the chrome isn't an option, by the very definition of full screen mode. So in that mode, you end up with awkward whitespace or rows and columns that don't fit on the screen.

Comment: there is no way to do the same in window mode? i have never had problem, i just need to zoom sometimes and then come back to the original size